# PHP Uncaught Error: Class "Items\ItemsView" not found when creating object inside a .load()-ed file

Tags: php

I have the following folder structure:

```
/classes
   /Items
      /items.class.php
      /itemsview.class.php 
         /class ItemsView

/includes
   /autoloader.inc.php
/parts
   /head.part.php
   /items.part.php
items.php
```

My `autoloader.inc.php` looks something like this:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register('autoload');

function autoload($className)
{
  $path = 'classes/';
  $ext  = '.class.php';
  $fullpath = $path . $className . $ext;

  if (!file_exists($fullpath)) {
    return false;
  }

  include_once $fullpath;
}
```

and it is included in the `head.inc.php` which is also included in every page. In addition, I have a div called `content-div` and a button that when clicked, loads the `items.part.php` to the `content-div` using ajax and jQuery's `.load()` function.

```
include head.inc.php
   include autoloader.inc.php

<div id="content-div">
   (items.part.inc is loaded here when button below is clicked)
<button>
```

Also, when loading the `items.part.php`, I also pass a data called `id`.

I can display the passed data to the *loaded* file, however, when I tried creating an *Item* object, I get the following error message:

*items.part.php*

```
  <?php
  $items = new Item\ItemsView();
  $items->getGatheringItemById($_POST['id']);
  ?>
```

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Item\ItemsView" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\dmp\parts\items.part.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dmp\parts\items.part.php on line 6**

The `items.class.php` has a namespace called `Item` and I have tried adding that both in `head.part.php`, in `items.php`, in `items.part.php` but still getting an error.

Comment: `Item\ItemsView` and `Items\itemsview` are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use `composer` with appropriate namespaces in your psr-4 autoload section. You would only need to require the `vendor/autoload.php` file and automagicly be able to use all your dependencies and custom librairies.

1. [Install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows)
2. Create your `composer.json` file. Eg.:

```js
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Classes\\Items\\": "classes/items"
        }
    }
}
```

3. Add to your classes items files the name space `Classes\Items`
4. Run the command `composer update`

> This creates the vendor directory with the autoload.php file

5. Add `require "vendor/autoload.php"`
6. Never have a class not found problem for the rest of your life and enjoy using other libraires with composer require command eg.: `composer require symfony/mailer`